# Click event returns undefined, but when I run a load event on the window the function works

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I am trying to simply put a word from my array into the DOM. When the button is clicked it returns undefined and if I console.log the randIndex I get `NaN`.

Ok, so I have tried to figure this out but I think I am missing something. When I click on the mealBtn it should run a function to show a meal item above the button. However, it returns undefined and puts undefined in the DOM. The thing that most confuses me is if I run an initialize function on window.load it does exactly what its suppose to.

```
    //load an item from menu on window load
    window.addEventListener('load', init);

    const mealBtn = document.getElementById('mealBtn');
    const currentMeal = document.getElementById('current-meal');
    const message = document.getElementById('message');

    const menu = [
      'Macaroni',
      'Burgers',
      'Chili',
      'Breakfast',
      'Chicken',
      'Take Out?'
    ];

    function init(){
      showMeal(menu);
    }

    mealBtn.addEventListener('click', showMeal);

    //show a meal from menu array
    function showMeal(menu){
      const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * menu.length);
      currentMeal.innerHTML = menu[randIndex];
      message.innerHTML = 'How about this?';
      message.style.color = '#003b6f'
    };
```

I expect that when I click the button it should give a menu suggestion in the DOM right above the button. It works on the init function when the window is loaded just not when the button is clicked.

Comment: try this :
        mealBtn.addEventListener('click', showMeal(menu));

Comment: @gakekobetsi, this just adds a bug to the OPs code.

Comment: ah sorry: this is the right answer : mealBtn.addEventListener('click', () => showMeal(menu));

Answer (score 1):

```
mealBtn.addEventListener('click', showMeal);
```

the argument being passed to `showMeal` when this is triggered is the event, not `menu`

you want either

```
mealBtn.addEventListener('click', () => showMeal(menu));
// or
mealBtn.addEventListener('click', showMeal.bind(null, menu));
```

The second is an example of partial application... it's succinct but not exactly immediately readable.

Comment: I took a look at it and changed the showMeal function being passed into the click event to the init function and that worked. But I see what you are saying, I figured it was something simple that I was just not seeing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Event listener callback in javascript accepts single parameter: object based on Event (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)).

MouseEvent (click) has a [detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) property, whoch can be used as `obj.addEventListener("click", (e) => doSomethingWith(e.detail))`

In your case, the Event parameter is no use to you and you want to pass custom parameters to the handler. Tyler's answer shows you the way to adapt the handler. However, you could also simply

```
mealBtn.addEventListener('click', init);
```